# table mutating in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table, `participated`, which has a trigger that returns the total damage amount for a driver id when a new record is inserted into the table.

```
create or replace trigger display  
  after insert on participated 
  for each row 
declare 
  t_id integer; 
  total integer;
begin
  select driver_id, sum(damage_amount) 
    into t_id, total 
    from participated  
    where :new.driver_id = driver_id 
    group by driver_id; 

  dbms_output.put_line(' total amount  ' || total' driver id' || t_id); 
end;
/
```

The trigger is created, but it returns this error:

```
ORA-04091: table SQL_HSATRWHKNJHKDFMGWCUISUEEE.PARTICIPATED is mutating, 
trigger/function may not see it ORA-06512: at 
"SQL_HSATRWHKNJHKDFMGWCUISUEEE.DISPLAY", line 5
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721
```

Please help with this trigger.

Comment: You can't query the table that fired the trigger, inside the trigger itself

Comment: Normally you would put this kind of logic in your application layer instead - when you do the insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented above, this feels like a code-smell. A row level trigger cannot change the table being changed, since that would fire another trigger, which would end up in an endless loop of calling triggers.

Changing this to a statement level trigger is not doing the same thing.

Preferred solution:
1) put this to the application logic, and calculate after row has been inserted - this is trivial as @kfinity mentioned.

2) earmark newly inserted rows and use a statement level trigger. For example, have an extra column, say is_new default 1 - therefore all new inserted rows will have this flag. Then use a statement level trigger suggested by @hbourchi to calculate and update all drivers that is_new is 1, and then set this flag back to zero

3) the logic in 2) can be implemented using pl/sql and in-memory pl/sql tables. The pl/sql table collects affected driver ids using a row level trigger, and then updates the totals of the selected drivers. Tom Kyte has lots of examples on this, this is not a rocket science, however if you lack of PL/SQL knowledge, then this is probably not your way. (For the note: PL/SQL *is* super important when using Oracle - without that Oracle is just an expensive Excel sheet like any other db. Worth of using it.)

4) probably, you shall revise your data model - and the problem solves itself. The *participated* table shows multiple rows per driver id. You want to calculate one total row per driver id - why would you put that summary to the same table? Simply add a new table, participated_total which has driver_id and damaged_amount fields. Then feel free to insert or update that from your trigger as you planned originally!

5) in fact, you can calculate these totals on the fly (depending on the number of rows and your performance expectations), by simply crafting the right SQL when querying - this way no need to store the pre-calculated totals.

6) but if you wish Oracle to store these totals for you, you can do 5) and use materialized views. These are in-fact tables, which are updated and maintained automatically by Oracle, so your actual query at 5) does not need to calculate anything on the fly but can get the automatically pre-calculated data from the materialized view.

Comment: Tank you for helping

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post your trigger definition but normally you can not query a table, inside trigger when updating records in the same table.

Try using after update trigger. it might work in your case. Something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER my_trigger AFTER UPDATE ON my_table FOR EACH ROW 

DECLARE
...
BEGIN
...
END;
```

another option would be to make your trigger AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER my_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON my_table FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
...
END;
```

However read this before choosing for this option:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems002.htm

Comment: This is not a full solution, as it won't work when multiple rows are inserted in one statement (note that OP inserts). For example, insert into ... select * from ....

Answer (score 0):

How about just no triggers at all ?

```
SQL> create table participated (
  2    incident_id int primary key,
  3    driver_id int not null,
  4    damage_amount int not null
  5  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> insert into participated
  2  select rownum, mod(rownum,10), dbms_random.value(1000,2000)
  3  from dual
  4  connect by level <= 200;

200 rows created.

SQL> create materialized view log on participated with rowid, (driver_id,damage_amount), sequence  including new values;

Materialized view log created.

SQL> create materialized view driver_tot
  2  refresh fast on commit
  3  with primary key
  4  as
  5  select driver_id,
  6         sum(damage_amount) tot,
  7         count(*) cnt
  8  from participated
  9  group by driver_id;

Materialized view created.

SQL> select driver_id, tot
  2  from driver_tot
  3  order by 1;

 DRIVER_ID        TOT
---------- ----------
         0      32808
         1      29847
         2      28585
         3      29714
         4      32148
         5      30491  <====
         6      29258
         7      32103
         8      30131
         9      26834

10 rows selected.

SQL>
SQL> insert into participated values (9999,5,1234);

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL>
SQL> select driver_id, tot
  2  from driver_tot
  3  order by 1;

 DRIVER_ID        TOT
---------- ----------
         0      32808
         1      29847
         2      28585
         3      29714
         4      32148
         5      31725  <====
         6      29258
         7      32103
         8      30131
         9      26834

10 rows selected.

SQL>
SQL>
```